# Help with this limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can you help me show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$

I have shown that $\lim_{x\to 0}x\log x=0$. I tried to use that $\log x\leq x-1, x>0$ or that $x\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ but I'm missing something.My problem is that I would like to absolutely bound by zero $x\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but not knowing if the logarithm is positive or negative creates the problem.

Comment: If $x^2+y^2 < 1$, then $\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \log \sqrt{1} = 0$, so $\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is negative for all $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to the origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints**:

Since $0 \le |x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, we have $0 \le \left|x\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right| \le \left|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right|$.

So first, show that $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r \to 0}r \log r = 0$. L'Hopital's Rule will help.

Then, apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks,that is exactly what I had in mind,but wasn't sure about the inequality. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In problems that involve $x^2+y^2$, polar coordinates are the default tool. We are interested in the limit as $r\to 0^+$ of $(\cos\theta)  r\log r$. By the familiar one-variable result, this is $0$.